# DNS configuration issue when enabling virtual subdomains

Tags: linux, domain-name-system, dns-hosting

I have a domain, let's call it example.com. Now on the registrar DNS configuration I have the following records:

1. A Record       *.example.com      xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx   TTL(Automatic)
2. A Record       @                  xxx.xxx.xxx.xx(same) TTL(Automatic)
3. CNAME          www                example.com    TTL(Automatic)

I want to create virtual subdomains, so when a user types for *.example.com(eg. as.example.com) the request is handled by the server installed on the main domain.

What can be wrong?

**Edit:** When I try to open for example ab.example.com on a server Google Chrome says **This webpage is not available** `DNS_PROBE_FINISHED_NXDOMAIN`

**Edit:** If I ping the main domain I get the correct answer, but If I ping the virtual subdomain then no response is obtained

Comment: What does `nslookup ab.example.com` return? It should return the ip address configured .If not, then check dns configuration again for mistakes. Post the exact dns configuration.

Answer (score 0):

There are two parts of the setup need to work. Check and make sure:

1. The DNS Name resolution is correct i.e. subdomain names resolve to the correct webserver IP. For example, `nslookup ab.example.com` or nslookup `cd.example.com` should return the same ip address of the webserver.
2. That webserver is handling the request correctly. This means in your case, for any request to *.example.com,  the server should return the website for example.com.

For example See this: https://www.siteground.com/kb/how_to_add_a_wildcard_dns_record/

Answer (score 0):

Problem solved using the following setup.

```
1. A Record   @      xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx    TTL(Automatic)
2. CNAME      *      xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx    TTL(Automatic)
```

The name resolution now is fine and the virtual subdomains are handled correctly.